# $u\bar{u}\rightarrow $ $\gamma \gamma$ propagator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, propagator

Why is the (red) propagator in this annihilation the $u$ quark? Why not $d$ quark or any other one?:
[image]

Also how can $u$ be a propagator, aren't the only propagetors bosons?

Comment: Electromagnetic interactions conserve...

Comment: conserve the flavour! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also how can u be a propagator, aren't the only propagators bosons?

No, they have to conserve quantum numbers and the appropriate couplings at the vertices, weak, electromagnetic, strong, but all particles in the elementary particle table of the standard model can be virtually exchanged,i.e.have a propagator in the integral representing the diagram.

Look at this [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) diagram:

[image]

where there is an off mass shell electron. (the off mass shell photon is necessary for energy- momentum conservation at the center of mass of the produced pair).

The pi0 is a clean electromagnetic decay.